# How do I know if my VS2012 has Entity Framework 5.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'd like to know if my VS2012 has been updated with Entity Framework 5.0.

Is it included in the VS2012.Update4 or what?

Rafael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 does not include any updates to EntityFramework. You can check out the release information here:

http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2013-nov-13-vs

If you want to update EntityFramework, you will need to update your project references to point to whichever version of EF your heart desires. `Nuget` is an excellent way to stay up to date with and easily manage your external dependencies. The link below should point you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906.aspx